Should we defer editing old off-topic posts until after they get closed?
This post What should I consider for a one month language program? was recently edited, after four years of inactivity.
While the edit itself is sensible (some unneeded tags were removed), it bumps the post up into the "Active" questions.
In this case the question is clearly off-topic. I believe it's not in our best interest to give prominence to such questions, via edits.
While the post activity has some benefits, as it prompts much needed close-votes, and it shows new users what kind of questions are likely to get downvoted, it has the side effect of cluttering the home page with off-topic content.
And there is always the risk that someone goes in and comments/answers, albeit in good faith, while we can't reach the 5 close votes threshold. As just happened here.
Should we defer curation work on these questions until after they get actually closed for good? (Flagging to bring it to other reviewers' attention might be appropriate)
Disclaimer: I'm not pointing fingers. I might have been guilty of this myself in the past. However today I've come across such a case, and I thought it's worth a discussion on meta.

Japanese SE recently had a community agreement to reduce the close vote thershhold to 3. I think it's a great idea to try this out. It's really discouraging for community-based moderation when close thresholds are constantly not met for much needed close questions.

@dROOOze:  I've been thinking about that option [perhaps create a post about it?]  However, I feel like we'd get to 5 close votes if we make close reasons clearer.  (For the present question, I'm not so sure it's clearly off-topic: questions that seek out experiences are considered "good subjective".  And I'm not sure if "study advice" has been officially declared off-topic by the community; it's not on the on-topic page.)  Also... if an answer does not attract 5 close votes, does that imply the community thinks it's okay?
